Unique legend in Seaborn and Matplotlib subplots
I am analysing some data and plotting three violin plots on two subplots using matplotlib and seaborn.
My problem is with the legends, I would like to have just one legend for the subplot outside them.
A MWE is:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.uniform(size=100), "B": np.random.uniform(size=100), "Class": np.random.randint(0, 4, 100)})

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

sns.violinplot(ax=axs[0], data=df[["A", "Class"]], x="Class", y="A")
axs[0].legend(["A"])

sns.violinplot(ax=axs[1], data=df[["B", "Class"]], x="Class", y="B", color="r")
axs[1].legend(["B"])

plt.show()


This example put one legend for each subplot, I want both of them together in the right side of the plot.
If I tried to extract the header and label in this way lines_labels = [ax.get_legend_handles_labels() for ax in fig.axes], but this is a list of empty tuple.
I tried to add a label option to the plots and plot the legend plt.legend(loc="center left", bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5)), but I obtain the same result of the plot I attached with the same legend repeated 4 times.
Any suggestion?

The best way is to correctly use the seaborn api, which prefers data in a long, not wide, format. dfm = df.melt(id_vars='Class') and plot with catplot g = sns.catplot(kind='violin', data=dfm, x='Class', y='value', col='variable', hue='variable'). However, adding color isn't necessary because the plots are already, more concisely, labeled. g = sns.catplot(kind='violin', data=dfm, x='Class', y='value', col='variable') don't unnecessarily use colors.

You can simply specify handles and labels in fig.legend():
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": np.random.uniform(size=100), "B": np.random.uniform(size=100), "Class": np.random.randint(0, 4, 100)})

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharey=True)

sns.violinplot(ax=axs[0], data=df[["A", "Class"]], x="Class", y="A")
sns.violinplot(ax=axs[1], data=df[["B", "Class"]], x="Class", y="B", color="r")

axs[0].set_ylabel("")

handle_a = axs[0].collections[0]
handle_b = axs[1].collections[0]

fig.legend(handles=[handle_a, handle_b], labels=["A", "B"], loc='center left', bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 0.5))

plt.show()



thanks for the answer, but the legend doesn't appear... at this point I think there is a problem somewhere else, but I don't know where...
